Why is my SQL query returning duplicate rows?
SELECT name, email
FROM users
JOIN orders ON users.id = orders.user_id
WHERE orders.status = 'completed';

I expect each user to appear only once in the result, but some users are listed multiple times. What might be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?
I'm running a SQL query to fetch data from a table, but I keep getting duplicate rows in the result set.

Please edit the question to include a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, including statements for creating/populating/querying your tables, as well as the observed results and the expected results.

Some users have multiple orders. Do SELECT * FROM and you'll see this.

When tagging a request with sql, always tag them with your DBMS, too. (In this case the DBMS doesn't really matter, but in other situations it can make a great difference which system you are using.)

When joining users and orders, you get the orders with their user attatched. If a user has three completed orders, you'll get three result rows for that user. And if you only show the user data and not the order data, you get three duplicate result rows. Demonstration:
The users table:



id
name
email




1
John
john@x.org


2
Jane
jane@x.org



The orders table:



id
what
user_id




1
one bag of fish
1


2
three hats
1


3
half a pair of shoes
1


4
a cake without cream
2



The joined data:



id
what
user_id
id
name
email




1
one bag of fish
1
1
John
john@x.org


2
three hats
1
1
John
john@x.org


3
half a pair of shoes
1
1
John
john@x.org


4
a cake without cream
2
2
Jane
jane@x.org



What you are showing:



name
email




John
john@x.org


John
john@x.org


John
john@x.org


Jane
jane@x.org



It is possible to SELECT DISTINCT users.name, users.email, but this is not how we write SQL queries. Why generate duplicates at all, when you must immediately get rid of them? Instead select all users for which exists a completed order:
SELECT name, email
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM orders o
              WHERE o.user_id = u.id AND o.status = 'completed');

The same can be done with an IN clause: Select all users that are in the completed-order group:
SELECT name, email
FROM users
WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id FROM orders WHERE status = 'completed');

The IN clause is often preferred for its readability in such simple scenarios. The EXISTS clause on the other hand can also be used for more complex lookups.
